How can one attain purity of mind and high spiritual powers?
Swami Vivekananda was a man whom everyone revered in his days and still today everyone respects . He attributed this quality to his purity of thoughts. How can one purify their thoughts and attain such spiritual powers and purity of mind ?which deity mantras can help and does maa Kali mantras help to burn such impurities in our mind and action? I am concluding this as swami Vivekananda and Ramakrishna paramahamsa were devotees of maa bhavatarini in Dakshineswar and these two were among the great stalwarts on those days , so will worshipping maa Kali help me get that purity of mind? And if someone commits some bad karmas and thoughts in this life and the previous lives can chanting maa Kali mantra help to burn all the accumulated bad karmas and impurities?? Thank you.
